# Is "bleed in a red" idiomatic?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

Is "bleed in a red" idiomatic?

> His body bled in a bright red before losing consciousness due to blood
> loss.

I almost find no instance of such a usage. Is this unidiomatic? I am pretty sure I've heard it a plenty of times, but I can't find any similar example on Google.

Comment: Bodies don't lose consciousness. People do.

Comment: You might as well say he bled in a very dark black, because he was a Goth.

Comment: We generally talk about someone's 'body' in the context of bleeding, etc, when they are dead. A person bleeds, and loses consciousness, not their body.

Comment: This is unidiomatic. Where have you actually read this? Poorly translated stuff from other languages don’t count. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an idiom. It's a literal description. The man was bleeding, and the blood was bright red.

It seems a slightly odd wording to me. I wouldn't say "bled in a bright red". I'd say, "He was bleeding bright red blood" or "His blood was bright red."

Comment: If the observer/narrator was unused to or shocked by the bleeding, the “in” could be part of how that is conveyed.

Comment: It's definitely not idiomatically correct. It's awkward wording at best.

Answer (score 2):

Not to dispute anything in previous answers, but they miss the semantic point of the quoted sentence.

To bleed in bright red is to bleed from an artery. Arterial blood is bright red because it is oxygenated and is en route to the body's tissues and organs to deliver that oxygen. Bleeding in bright red is a dire emergency due to the large amount of blood that can be lost from an artery. If not stopped through immediate first aid, there is a high likelihood of rapid unconsciousness and death.

To bleed in dark red (actually [dark reddish-purple](https://mriquestions.com/why-are-veins-blue.html)) is to bleed from a vein. Venous blood has already given up its oxygen to organs and tissues. Bleeding in dark red is a lesser emergency and is less likely to cause rapid unconsciousness and death.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey because "he bled blood" is pleonasm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Semantic_pleonasm